# Reloading/animating a UICollectionView alongside a layout change

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40680588/uicollectionviewcell-contents-do-not-animate-alongside-cells-contentview) (and its answer) have got me half way to what I want.

But now I'm stuck on the next part and (to be honest) I'm not even sure if it's possible.

I have defined a cell like so...

```
class ExpandableCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var priority: Expandable.Priority = .low {
        didSet {
            imageView.isHidden = priority != .high
        }
    }

    private let imageView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .red
        v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        return v
    }()

    private let label: UILabel = {
        let l = UILabel()
        l.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        l.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .headline)
        l.numberOfLines = 0
        l.text = "Tap Me!"
        l.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)
        l.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
        l.textAlignment = .center
        return l
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        let labelStack: UIStackView = {
            let s = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [label])
            s.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            s.axis = .vertical
            s.alignment = .center
            s.distribution = .equalCentering
            s.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
            return s
        }()

        let stackView: UIStackView = {
            let s = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [imageView, labelStack])
            s.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            s.axis = .horizontal
            s.spacing = 10
            s.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
            s.alignment = .fill
            s.distribution = .fill
            s.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
            return s
        }()

        addSubview(stackView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            ])

        clipsToBounds = true

        backgroundColor = UIColor.init(white: 0.8, alpha: 1.0)

        layer.cornerRadius = 6
    }

    func display(button: DigestButton) {
        label.text = button.title
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func apply(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) {
        super.apply(layoutAttributes)
        layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

It has three possible states (small, medium or large) which are set by the priority.

I am updating the layout of the collection view to update the size based on the priority stored in the data.

It works like this...

[image]

As you can see from this bit of code...

```
var priority: Expandable.Priority = .low {
    didSet {
        imageView.isHidden = priority != .high
    }
}
```

Updating the priority will show/hide the "imageView" in the cell. It is just a standard `UIView` for the purposes of a proof of concept.

But it is only showing/hiding the `imageView` after the layout has finished updating.

As per the linked question I am updating the layout of things using the code...

```
collectionView.performBatchUpdates(nil) { _ in
    // completion block
    collectionView.reloadItems(at: changedIndexPaths)
}
```

I am reloading the data for the changed cell in the completion block. (Hence the update after the animation has finished).

If I move it like this...

```
collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
    collectionView.reloadItems(at: changedIndexPaths)
}) { _ in
    // completion block
}
```

Then the animation changes to this...

[image]

... which is worse than how I started.

Is there a way to animate the change to the state of the cell? Ideally I'd like the image view to animate in at the same rate as the layout animation.

If I'm not changing the stuff inside the cell then this isn't an issue. But in some case I will want to change the stuff inside the cell and I'd like it to be a smooth transition either way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK... I'm adding this here as a preliminary answer but I think I just cracked it.

The trick is to pass any information required during the animation of the layout into the cell by means of the `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes`.

From the docs it says that you can subclass the layout attributes to add additional information in them that is required by the layout.

By putting the `priority` information into the layout attributes I can now animate the image view coming into view at the same time as the cell moves and resizes.

Boom! :D

OK... subclassing UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes like this...

```
fileprivate class PriorityLayoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
    var priority: DigestExpandable.Priority? = nil

    override func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {
        let copy = super.copy(with: zone) as! PriorityLayoutAttributes
        copy.priority = self.priority
        return copy
    }

    override func isEqual(_ object: Any?) -> Bool {
        guard let rhs = object as? PriorityLayoutAttributes else {
            return false
        }

        return super.isEqual(rhs) && priority == rhs.priority
    }
}
```

... and then using those attributes for this particular cell.

In the cell I updated the `apply(_)` function like this...

```
override func apply(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) {
    super.apply(layoutAttributes)

    if let attributes = layoutAttributes as? PriorityLayoutAttributes,
        let priority = attributes.priority {
        self.priority = priority
    }

    layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Now it works and animates beautifully :D

[image]