# Animating the expansion of a UICollectionViewCell's content upon selection

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionviewcell, uianimation

How to animate the expansion of a UICollectionViewCell's content upon selection?

Currently I'm using transition animation on my didSelectItemAtIndexPath for animating a view Which isn’t working smoothly like AppStore card animation.

Here is my current code...

```
AnimateStaticImageViewController *animateImageVC = [[AnimateStaticImageViewController alloc] init];
animateImageVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
animateImageVC.modelImage = [UIImage imageNamed:text];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.7 animations:^{
        animateImageVC.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1.0, 1.3);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.7 animations:^{
            animateImageVC.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.9, 0.9);
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.7 animations:^{
                animateImageVC.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
            }];
        }];
    }];
    
[self presentViewController:animateImageVC animated:NO completion:nil];
```

Comment: There is an api on the collectionViewLayout... let me see if I can wrack my brains to find it. I think it will do what you want.

Comment: Is it [AnimatedCollectionViewLayout](https://github.com/KelvinJin/AnimatedCollectionViewLayout) ?  I need something written on objective c. Thank you !

Comment: No, it was my own code not a framework. I was just using UICollectionViewLayout. I think I might have a question on here about it. Still looking :D

Comment: Here you go... I think this is what you're asking... although it's a bit vague in the question. But it sounds like you want to animate the content of the cells at the same time as animating the layout of the collection view. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51236002/reloading-animating-a-uicollectionview-alongside-a-layout-change Just a note... that question and answer is written in Swift but (aside from the slight syntax change) everything should just work straight into Objective-C. It's just using vanilla UICollectionView.

Comment: Just checking if the question I linked was the same issue that you are having in this question? Thanks

Comment: I just fixed the issue with another third party lib [here](https://github.com/recruit-mp/RMPZoomTransitionAnimator). BTW thank you @Fogmeister  !

Comment: You should add an answer to your question so that others with the same issue can see how you solved the problem.

Comment: Done answering ! Sorry for the late as I was fixing some minor bugs. @Fogmeister

Answer (score 1):

So, I was trying a modal transition animation in my app's home page staticImageCollectionView immediately after clicking the image.
The core animation & transform mechanism didn't work for me as I need something like AppStore's card animation.
Using [this library](https://github.com/recruit-mp/RMPZoomTransitionAnimator) worked after some hassle! Following this...

1. Setting the library with [following steps](https://github.com/recruit-mp/RMPZoomTransitionAnimator#use-for-a-modal-transition).
2. Calling the transitioningDelegate of the animationViewController on didSelectItemAtIndexPath (or prepareForSegue if working with segue-navigation controller).
3. Calling it within a completion block to ignore flickering & delay issue in view presentation.

```
AnimatedStaticImageViewController *animateImageVC = [[AnimatedStaticImageViewController alloc] init];
animateImageVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
animateImageVC.modelImage = [UIImage imageNamed:text];
    
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                     animations:^{
        animateImageVC.transitioningDelegate = self;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self.view removeFromSuperview];
        [self presentViewController:animateImageVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}];
```

4. Be careful when setting imageView which is the main presentation of the animation.
5. Make sure you declaring the delegate 'RMPZoomTransitionAnimating' & 'RMPZoomTransitionDelegate' methods on both fromViewController and toViewController.